# Load external page (not same domain) into div using Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, sencha-touch, mobile-application

I have a setup I am trying to build that basically acts as a web browser proxy.

Basically, we have an app which we have written which iPhone users are able to bookmark to their home screen.  When they view the content in our application, occasionally they will get a URL that directs them to another website.  When they follow this URL after launching the app from their home screen it loads it in the app itself, removing the app that they were working on (which is not okay behavior for our application).  I have been told that if we add a querystring ("?") at the end of it then it will launch the new page in Safari instead.

This would be acceptable behavior, except when they bring up the application from their home screen again it reloads the page and they lose their place from wherever they were at (which, again, is not acceptable).

To circumvent this, for iPhone users, I have added in a div that is intended to be used to load the page they wanted to view INSIDE of our application so they can still have a back button to get back to where they were.  This would be perfect, except we are getting security sandbox violations when trying to load the external page (obviously)

What would you guys recommend in order to resolve this problem?  Keep in mind that there is more than one way to skin this cat and I'm perfectly happy going with a better solution if anyone has any suggestions.

The only suggestion I can come up with is for us to turn the app into a native iOS application so that when the user leaves the application it can multitask in the background and retain it's state.  We want to avoid this if at all possible as there are a whole slew of extra logistics we would have to incorporate to get this to work with our other tools we are using.

Comment: forgot to mention that...we looked into this route and it doesnt work as our site is loaded via SSL and if the site we are loading is not SSL it appears to block it for security reasons...Either that or the external sites do not support embeding, and as we dont have control over the external sites (nor do we know which sites will be linked) we cant circumvent that I dont think